# Scala - Couldn't remove double quotes for Key -> value "{}" braces while building Json

Tags: json, scala, generics, gatling, stringescapeutils

Scala - Couldn't remove double quotes for "{}" braces while building Json

```
import scala.util.Random
import math.Ordered.orderingToOrdered
import math.Ordering.Implicits.infixOrderingOps
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json.Writes
import play.api.libs.json.Json.JsValueWrapper

val data1 = (1 to 2)
.map {r => Json.toJson(Map(
                "name" -> Json.toJson(s"Perftest${Random.alphanumeric.take(6).mkString}"),
                "domainId"->Json.toJson("343RDFDGF4RGGFG"),
                "value" ->Json.toJson("{}")))}
val data2 = Json.toJson(data1)
println(data2)
```

**Result** :
[{"name":"PerftestpXI1ID","domainId":"343RDFDGF4RGGFG",**"value":"{}"**},{"name":"PerftestHoZSQR","domainId":"343RDFDGF4RGGFG",**"value":"{}"**}]

**Expected** :
"value":{}

[{"name":"PerftestpXI1ID","domainId":"343RDFDGF4RGGFG",**"value":{}**},{"name":"PerftestHoZSQR","domainId":"343RDFDGF4RGGFG",**"value":{}**}]

Please suggest a solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are giving it a `String` so it is creating a string in JSON. What you actually want is an empty dictionary, which is a `Map` in Scala:

```
val data1 = (1 to 2)
  .map {r => Json.toJson(Map(
                  "name" -> Json.toJson(s"Perftest${Random.alphanumeric.take(6).mkString}"),
                  "domainId"->Json.toJson("343RDFDGF4RGGFG"),
                  "value" ->Json.toJson(Map.empty[String, String])))}
```

More generally you should create a `case class` for the data and create a custom `Writes` implementation for that class so that you don't have to call `Json.toJson` on every value.

---

Here is how to do the conversion using only a single `Json.toJson` call:

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json

case class MyData(name: String, domainId: String, value: Map[String,String])
implicit val fmt = Json.format[MyData]

val data1 = (1 to 2)
  .map { r => new MyData(
      s"Perftest${Random.alphanumeric.take(6).mkString}",
      "343RDFDGF4RGGFG",
      Map.empty
    )
  }
val data2 = Json.toJson(data1)
println(data2)
```

The `value` field can be a standard type such as `Boolean` or `Double`. It could also be another `case class` to create nested JSON as long as there is a similar `Json.format` line for the new type.

More complex JSON can be generated by using a custom `Writes` (and `Reads`) implementation as described in the documentation.

Comment: how to handle non string value like date, boolean or double value
here
"value" ->Json.toJson(Map.empty[String, String])

Comment: Thank you.
in the above example I am getting error at implicit val fmt = Json.format[MyData].
stating implicit value should be explicit.
please help me with the Writes and Reads documentation links

Comment: [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/LBv2OVinSGqtOhKYA3vXwQ) is a link to working code, so really not sure why it isn't working for you.

Comment: Thank you for analysing and supporting
in the code the attribute type of value should be Any. yes the code works for double.

Comment: I strongly suggest avoiding `Any` and using a much more constrained type. There is no way that the JSON library can process `Any` because it has no idea what it might contain.  If you have a specific problem that you think requires `Any` then consider asking a separate question about that.